# Laravel 4 - Extend Pagination Class

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Is there a way to extend the Pagination Class of Laravel 4 ?

I tried some things but nothing good...

I'm here :

**PaginationServiceProvider.php**

```
class PaginationServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider {
    /**
     * Indicates if loading of the provider is deferred.
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $defer = false;

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application events.
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(){
        $this->package('thujohn/pagination');
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     * @return void
     */
    public function register(){
        $this->app['paginator'] = $this->app->share(function($app){
            $paginator = new Environment($app['request'], $app['view'], $app['translator']);
            $paginator->setViewName($app['config']['view.pagination']);
            return $paginator;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get the services provided by the provider.
     * @return array
     */
    public function provides(){
        return array();
    }
}
```

**Environment.php**

```
class Environment extends \Illuminate\Pagination\Environment {
    public function hello(){
        return 'hello';
    }
}
```

I replaced **'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider',** by **'Thujohn\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider',**

When I call **$test->links()** it's ok

When I call **$test->hello()** it fails

When I call **Paginator::hello()** it's ok

Any idea ?

Comment: $test is an instance of your Environment?

Comment: Like in the doc ;)
http://laravel.com/docs/pagination#usage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everyting is fine except that `Paginator::make()` returns `Paginator` instance, not `Environment`.

You should move Your method to `Paginator` class.

Today I've posted on GH my extension for `Paginator`. You can check it as a reference  [desmart/pagination](http://github.com/desmart/pagination)